# Hide Navigation Controller Back Button iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, back-button

I have tried to hide the back button in my navigation controller by adding the following lines to my `viewDidLoad` method. Many other previous answers on SO have said this works, so I don't know what my problem is? Maybe something new with iOS 7 / Xcode 5?

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: Are self.navigationItem and self.navigationController.navigationItem returning non-nil objects?

Comment: NO this will also work with iOS7/Xcode5... May be issue with your Stack of Project designed...

Comment: @Cutetare how do I determine if they are returning non-nil objects? I set a break point on the lines, but navigationController does not show up under self in debug console window. Also I should add that I created this view controller in storyboard, so will that cause this code to not work?

Comment: @KumarKl could it be because I created the view controller using storyboards?

Comment: You can either simply `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationItem)` or set a breakpoint, and in the debug console (the same part where the NSLogs are kept, not the left part), when your breakpoint is reached, and the console is asking (lldb), just type  `po self.navigationItem`. This should work even if you are using storyboard (assuming you have connected your objects appropriatly).

Answer (score 36):

I too had faced similar issue.
This will work only when you have not customized your `Navigation bar`.
Either one of the below one will work.

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];   OR
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Please check whether your getting "Back" in `iOS 7`, then the above will work.

Hope this will help you to identify the issue

Answer (score 7):

In `UINavigationController` we can hide Like this:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

And In `UITabBarController` we can Hide Like this:

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
```

Comment: Please add some explaination why/how this code works and why the OPs code doesn't if you can

Comment: I just create a empty leftBarButton to hide backButton.And OPs code is work ok .I think he has another bug.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: this is the only way i've found to correctly hide the back button from every caller piece of code

Answer (score 2):

Use following code :

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES]; // hide back button

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:nil]; // set as nil

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];  // left bar item as nil
```