# iOS 8: UINavigationController hide back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, back-button, iphone-6

After I run my application in iOS 8 (XCode 6.0.1, iPhone 6), the back button does not hide.

My code:

```
- (void)removeCategoriesButton
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [_navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
        [_navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
    } else {
        UIViewController *controller = _app.window.rootViewController;

        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)controller;
            [nav.topViewController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
            [nav.topViewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

But the back button does not hide (see screenshot):

[image: Simulator screen]

**UPD:**

I run application in another simulators, and i see this "bug" only on iOS 8.

Comment: In iPad all OK. Back button success hide. Can this bug in iOS?

Comment: Also having this issue, did you find a solution?
For me the back button doesn't function either, unless I remove setHidesBackButton:YES

Comment: please check this out self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil http://stackoverflow.com/a/21829432/2584566

Answer (score 45):

This worked for me.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Home"];
}
```

Comment: this works but it momentarily shows the back button before hiding it

Comment: Yeah - I did notice that. I've started writing in Swift now and it appears to work in the viewDidLoad without any problem.

Comment: hmm.. strange, I am using swift as well and still having issues with doing it in viewDidLoad

Comment: swift code  = self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

Answer (score 15):

I tried many of the answers but the only one that worked for me was:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}
```

Comment: This works. Previously I'd tried `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];` but the back button text still remained.

Answer (score 6):

Call on your ViewDidLoad the following method:

Objective-C:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Swift:

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Comment: I try call this code from `viewDidLoad` but not working.

Comment: Then try to call it on the ViewController that takes to this. For example if this is your second ViewController write the code I posted on the first ViewController ViewDidLoad method

Answer (score 4):

Swift:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that this was caused by pushing a new view in viewWillAppear, if I moved it to viewDidAppear then the back button didn't show. Strange that this issue only appeared in iOS8.

Comment: Nice hint, but for me, it was only in iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",view.class];
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"UINavigationItemButtonView"] || [name isEqualToString:@"_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView"]) {
        [view setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where have you written that code?

It should be as simple as in your view controller's loadView/viewDidLoad: method adding this

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

This works for me on an iPhone 6

Comment: Hmm... Not working. I added call this method in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This code `removeCategoriesButton ` called from controller - `viewWillAppear`, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` in `viewWillAppear()` method, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the back button using setHidesBackButton only works if you have not customized the button.

From the method reference: "Specify true if the back button should be hidden when this navigation item is the top item. Specify false if the back button should be visible, assuming it has not been replaced by a custom item."
(Note the last line)

The simply solution in that case is to first set the leftBarButtonItem to nil.

Swift 3.0:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug only happens when you use Storyboard. Another solution is add an UIBarButtonItem with empty title to "fake" it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do this is to hide the navigation bar and adding a navigation bar in storyboard and redisplay the navigation bar in the next ViewController. All I had to do is add a label in the status bar so that the navigation bar is uniform. I have found no other way...

[image: screen]

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

so that the navigation bar is displayed in the next viewcontroller, declare in:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}
```